# Unity - trying to add items at specific locations in Mapbox

Tags: unity-game-engine, geolocation, mapbox, latitude-longitude

I´ve followed a tutorial on YouTube where the developer added items spawning around the player at a certain interval with a max distance on the tile in MapBox. What I am trying to achieve is to add them at specific longitude and latitudes.

The changes I made was to to loop through the max amount of items I want to add, incrementing an i variable. Then instead of spawning the item around the player like `newLat = getPlayerPosition() + random;` I hardcoded the lat and lon like: `case 0: newLat = 48.30791f; newLon = 18.08611f; millenium_item.tag = "MI0"; break;`

And each item is added to a list of items.
The behaviour I am expecting is to add each item to the list and then spawn them on the map, but instead only one item gets added, the one that has the exact same latitude and longitude as the player:

```
case 3: newLat = 48.32232f; newLon = 18.09462f; millenium_item.tag = "MI3"; break;
```

Case 3 gets added as it has the same Lat and Lon as my player (where the phone actually is).

```
case 4: newLat = 48.32232f; newLon = 18.09538f; millenium_item.tag = "MI4"; break;
```

Case 4 doesnt get added, but as you can see it is pretty close to the location of Case 3.

I dont know what I am doing wrong. Full code:

```
void SpawnItems() {

        itemindex = 100;
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (googleSignIn.locationdata[i] == false)
            {
            MilleniumItemType type = (MilleniumItemType)(int)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(MilleniumItemType)).Length);
            float newLat = 0; 
            float newLon = 0;

            MilleniumPuzzle prefab = Resources.Load("MilleniumItems/puzzle", typeof(MilleniumPuzzle)) as MilleniumPuzzle;
            MilleniumPuzzle millenium_item = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(-100, 0, 0)) as MilleniumPuzzle;
            millenium_item.tileManager = tileManager;

                switch (i)
                {
                     ...
                case 3: newLat = 48.32232f; newLon = 18.09462f; millenium_item.tag = "MI3"; break;
                case 4: newLat = 48.32232f; newLon = 18.09538f; millenium_item.tag = "MI4"; break;
                case 5: newLat = 48.32310f; newLon = 18.09536f; millenium_item.tag = "MI5"; break;
                     ...
                }
                /// OUR LAT: 48.32232 OUR LON: 18.09462

                    millenium_item.Init(newLat, newLon);
                    items.Add(millenium_item);
        }
        }
```

Then Init looks like this:

```
public void Init(float _lat, float _lon) {
    lat = _lat;
    lon = _lon;
    UpdatePosition ();
}
```

and:

```
public void UpdatePosition() {
    float x, y;
    Vector3 position = Vector3.zero;

    geodeticOffsetInv (tileManager.getLat * Mathf.Deg2Rad, tileManager.getLon * Mathf.Deg2Rad, lat * Mathf.Deg2Rad, lon * Mathf.Deg2Rad, out x, out y);

    if ((lat - tileManager.getLat) < 0 && (lon - tileManager.getLon) > 0 || (lat - tileManager.getLat) > 0 && (lon - tileManager.getLon) < 0) {
        position = new Vector3(x, .5f, y);
    }
    else {
        position = new Vector3 (-x, .5f, -y);
    } 

    position.x *= 0.300122f;
    position.z *= 0.123043f;

    Debug.Log("Position of inited millenium puzzle: " + position.x + " z: " + position.z);

    transform.position = position;
}
```

Comment: Is there an error in the error log?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the code and debugging it? What is the value of `count`?

Comment: the count is 21, as I am trying to add 21 items, there are no errors, the items just dont show up, I dont know if it is possible to spawn them at exact coordinates

Comment: do they show up in the hierarchy view?

Comment: What is content of `googleSignIn.locationdata`? How many times do you see the log `Position of inited millennium puzzle ...`? In generalaybe check your cameras far clipping plane ... Possible that all objects are there but only invisible to you?

Comment: They dont show up in the hierarchy, they never did, I guess because I dont have a GPS preview in the editor. The content of `googleSignIn.locationdata` is all false if the player haven´t picked up any items yet. Position of the inited puzzles were correct, they were the ones I added. I also added a link to the GitHub of the project if anyone wants to check it out. Its the scene called Map, the scripts are MilleniumItemManager and MilleniumPuzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue myself. Adding the items at exact coordinates never worked, so instead I am saving the item coordinates in an array. Then in `update()` I am comparing the position of the player with the coordinates where the items should be. If the difference between the positions are between constant numbers that I defined, then the items will appear around the player, although not exactly at the building, but in my case I don´t mind.
Example:

```
   `public void SpawnItems() {

    itemindex = 100;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {

        if (googleSignIn.locationdata[i] == false && spawnedItem[i] == false)
        {
            if(tileManager.getLat - itemLats[i] < 0.003f && tileManager.getLat - itemLats[i] > -0.003f && tileManager.getLon - itemLons[i] < 0.00103f && tileManager.getLon - itemLons[i] > -0.00103f)
            {
                    MilleniumItemType type = (MilleniumItemType)(int)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(MilleniumItemType)).Length);


                    MilleniumPuzzle prefab = Resources.Load("MilleniumItems/puzzle", typeof(MilleniumPuzzle)) as MilleniumPuzzle;
                    MilleniumPuzzle millenium_item = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.Euler(-100, 0, 0)) as MilleniumPuzzle;
                    millenium_item.tileManager = tileManager;

                    float newLat = tileManager.getLat + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.0001f, 0.0001f);
                    float newLon = tileManager.getLon + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.0001f, 0.0001f);

                    if(newLat == previousLat || newLon == previousLon)
                {
                     newLat = tileManager.getLat + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.0001f, 0.0001f);
                     newLon = tileManager.getLon + UnityEngine.Random.Range(-0.0001f, 0.0001f);
                }

                previousLon = newLon;
                previousLat = newLat;

                    spawnedItem[i] = true;

                    millenium_item.tag = "MI" + i;

                    millenium_item.Init(newLat, newLon);
                    items.Add(millenium_item);  
            }
    }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say exactly what is causing this, but this block of code has a good chance of getting an index out of range exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (googleSignIn.locationdata[i] == false)
    {
```

Instead, you should do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < googleSignIn.locationdata.length; i++)
{
    if (googleSignIn.locationdata[i] == false)
    {
```

But, there is another problem.

Both this class and the `googleSignIn` class initialize themselves in `Start()`, and you are not guaranteed that `googleSignIn` will execute first.  To fix this, you should move the `SpawnItems();` call to `Awake()` instead of `Start()`

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it didnt work, although the first part of your response makes the code cleaner, its the same thing, locationdata.length and count are the exact same number. As for putting it to `Awake()`, the scene is inaccessible to users, who didnt log in, so `googleSignIn` will always execute sooner. The main problem is that there are absolutely NO tutorials, about putting items at exact coordinates, only spawning around player. Therefore I dont know if it is possible and if so, how. My modified code doesn´t work. If you have time please check the GitHub project. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MapBox, the Location-based game example has a map where you can add Layers now. Choose the Data source 'Mapbox Streets' and then Add a Point of interest using the specify long/latitude option. This lets you spawn prefabs at those coordinates.